# adding a tabstrip to nopcommerce product details in user website as in the product details in admin site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, nopcommerce

I Would like to know by an example how to add a tabstrip to the product detail page in nopcommerce user website as the one in the admin website, because I want to change the view of the product and I want to implement this as a plugin! am I thinking right?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NopCommerce part

To add content using plugins NopCommerce uses WidgetZones which are put throughout default theme like

```
@Html.Widget("productdetails_before_collateral")
```

Once you figure out widget zone you want to place your widget in, you must implement interface **IWidgetPlugin** and you must define list of zones where you want your widget rendered

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
    return new List<string>() { "productdetails_before_collateral" };
}
```

*You can look at source of NivoSlider or GoogleAnalytics widgets on how they do it.*

## Telerik Part

Reference it in your view

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
```

And then just use the helper

```
@Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("myplugin-tabstrip").Items(x =>
{
    x.Add().Text(T("localized-tab-1").Text).Content("Foo bar").Selected(true);
    x.Add().Text(T("localized-tab-2").Text).Content("Foo bar 2");
})
```

Note: If you want to place different content instead of existing or add into places without widget zones I'm afraid you have to change ProductTemplate views in your theme.